# OpenERP version 6, My Timesheet form crashed after inherited

Tags: odoo

In OpenERP version 6, in my custom module, I changed the Timesheet form view by inheriting as my custom view below:

```
<record id="oit_hr_timesheet_sheet_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">oit.hr.timesheet.sheet.form</field>
        <field name="model">hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet_sheet.hr_timesheet_sheet_form" />
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <button name="sign_in" position="replace"/>
                <button name="sign_out" position="replace"/>
                <field name="state_attendance" position="after">
                    <field name="day_attendance"/>
                </field>
                <field name="total_attendance_day" position="replace"/>
                <field name="total_difference_day" position="replace"/>
                <field name="total_timesheet_day" position="replace"/>
                <field name="timesheet_ids" position="after">
                    <field name="day_difference"/>
                <field name="day_timesheet"/>
                </field>
                <page string="By Day" position="replace" />
                <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="Time balance">
                        <group colspan="4" col="2" width="600">
                            <field name="time_account_balance"/>
                            <field name="working_hour"/>
                            <field name="attendance_hour"/>
                            <separator string="Timesheet numbers until the viewed working period." colspan="4" />
                            <field name="total_time_account_balance"/>
                            <field name="total_working_hour"/>
                            <field name="total_attendance_hour"/>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                  </notebook>
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Then the Human Resources / Time Tracking / My Timesheet form totaly crash. But when I go to Administration / Customization / User Interface / Menu Items, and I choose "My Timesheet" menu item to fix its action from "ir.actions.server" to "ir.actions.act_window" and select object "hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet", then choose my view "oit.hr.timesheet.sheet.form" for object's form view, choose my view "oit.hr.timesheet.sheet.tree.simplified" for object's tree view.

Then I have "My Timesheet" form shown correctly.
Why is that? I think there is somethings in my view code not work with "My Timesheet" menu and "ir.actions.server" defined in file hr_timesheet_sheet/hr_timesheet_sheet_data.xml, Here I paste the openerp6 code in hr_timesheet_sheet_data.xml:

```
<record id="ir_actions_server_timsheet_sheet" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field eval="5" name="sequence"/>
        <field eval="&quot;&quot;&quot;code&quot;&quot;&quot;" name="state"/>
        <field eval="&quot;&quot;&quot;ir.actions.server&quot;&quot;&quot;" name="type"/>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_hr_timesheet_current_open"/>
        <field eval="[(6,0,[])]" name="child_ids"/>
        <field eval="&quot;&quot;&quot;action = self.pool.get('hr.timesheet.current.open').open_timesheet(cr, uid, object.id, context)&quot;&quot;&quot;" name="code"/>
        <field eval="&quot;&quot;&quot;True&quot;&quot;&quot;" name="condition"/>
        <field eval="&quot;&quot;&quot;My Timesheet&quot;&quot;&quot;" name="name"/>
    </record>
    <record id="menu_act_hr_timesheet_sheet_form_my_current" model="ir.ui.menu">
        <field name="name">My Timesheet</field>
        <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>
        <field name="parent_id" ref="hr_attendance.menu_hr_time_tracking"/>
        <field name="icon">STOCK_JUSTIFY_FILL</field>
        <field name="action" ref="ir_actions_server_timsheet_sheet"/>
    </record>
```

Kindly please help me to have correct view code or a solution so that I will not need to change information for menu "My Timesheet" after I upgrade my custom module! thanks a lot!

Comment: An error stack trace would help determine the issue. Can you please post it.

Comment: post ur error log here that will help to traceback

Comment: Hi friends, currently I'm having this log when open the "My Timesheet" form, but I don't think it shows the problem, because I get it when having my custom module installed and when not having my module installed too. Anyway, I paste the log string here:
WARNING:osv.browse_record.ir.actions.act_window:No field_values found for ids [1553L] in browse_record(ir.actions.act_window, 1553)
Thanks for your help!